# Feedback to improve a slow algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting

I'm having trouble creating a performant function for the following problem. I'm building a time-table and I need to separate an array of items in columns so that no column has 2 items that share an hour in their start/end hour range.

My current solution works but does a bunch of wasteful computation specially in the worst case where all the items have the same hour range and it creates a new column per each item.

```
function getItemsPerColumn(items) {
  let itemsPerHour = {},
      itemsPerColumn = {},
      itemsCount = items.length,
      currentHour = 8,
      columnIndex = 1;

  items.forEach(item => {
    let start = moment(item.startHour),
        end = moment(item.endHour),
        startHour = start.format('H'),
        endHour = end.format('H');

    if (itemsPerHour[startHour] === undefined) { itemsPerHour[startHour] = []; }
    itemsPerHour[startHour].push({
      rowStart: startHour,
      rowEnd: endHour,
      item: item
    });
  });

  while (itemsCount > 0) {
    if (itemsPerHour[currentHour] !== [] && itemsPerHour[currentHour] !== undefined) {
      if (itemsPerColumn[columnIndex] === undefined) { itemsPerColumn[columnIndex] = []; }
      let nextHour = itemsPerHour[currentHour][0].rowEnd;
      itemsPerColumn[columnIndex].push(itemsPerHour[currentHour].shift());
      currentHour = nextHour - 1;
      itemsCount--;
    }
    if (currentHour === 18) {
      currentHour = 8;
      columnIndex++;
    }
    else currentHour++;
  }
  return itemsPerColumn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to [Interval scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling). You can find a optimal solution like [this](https://github.com/kartikkukreja/blog-codes/blob/master/src/Interval%20Scheduling%20Problem.cpp) (C++ language).

Answer (score 0):

Make array/list of triplets `{Time, StartOrEnd, ItemId}` for all interval ends.
Here `StartOrEnd` is `+1` for start of interval, and `-1` for the end of interval

Sort them by `Time` key. If tie for `Time` happens (equal times), use the secondary key: `-1` before `+1`

Make `Counter=0`

Walk through array, adding `StartOrEnd` for current record value to `Counter`

Assign `ItemId` of current record to `Counter-th` column